# Question about England Qualification Framework

Tags: united-kingdom, qualifications

I'm a student from China and want to apply for a MSc program in UK. While filling the online forms I am supposed to choose my qualification but I'm confused about the England Qualification Framework.

I got my bachelor's degree and graduation certification of Jilin University after 4 years' study. Which one should I choose from the list?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

A foreign bachelors would be a "Non-UK first degree", *first degree* in this case meaning undergraduate degree, or a degree taken by someone who doesn't already have a degree.

Confusingly, in the UK "first" is also used as [a degree classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_undergraduate_degree_classification#Degree_classification) for bachelors degrees.

Comment: Thanks for your information. :P